# Setting Contact mandatory in Cases

Tags: trigger, validation-rule

Our org Cases in SF, contacts are not set as mandatory. I want to set it to mandatory by using a validation rule to associate with Contacts. But the validation rule will not work, as we have designed the Cases to be auto created after an account ownership is changed. This is built in apex code. How do we implement the validation rule without impacting the create cases but disallow user to save the case when there is an edit or close without populating contact in Cases.Does trigger help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for a trigger or validation rule. Simply go to the Case Page Layout, and mark the Contact field as required. This will force the field to be required in the UI, but not for Apex, API calls, etc.

## Classic

Click on Setup > Customize > Cases > Page Layouts > Edit (Layout Name), double-click the Contact field, or click the Wrench icon > check Required > Save.

## Lightning

Click on Setup > Object Manager > Case > Case Page Layouts > (Layout Name), double-click the Contact field, or click the Wrench icon > check Required > Save.

Comment: The Apex creates new case with change of ownership, will it impact creating failure unable to create new case due to unavailability of contact populated?

Comment: @user10866 it shouldn't have any problems.